# AWS Glue Tutorial fails when trying to run crawler

Tags: aws-glue

I'm trying to run the AWS Glue Tutorial. I have full access to all AWS' services. When I try to run the crawler, it returns to me the following message:

> "aws_glue/AWS-Crawler is not authorized to perform: glue:GetDatabase on resource: xxx:xxx:glue:xxxx:xxxxxx:xxxx (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: xxx). For more information, see Setting up IAM Permissions in the Developer Guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/getting-started-access.html)."

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I missed the Glue Role. If anyone face same problem, just change the role to AWSGlueServiceRole-AWSDBBlog-Glue-Tutorial.